En Selenium con Python usando webdriver.Chrome siempre aparece la opción de "Elige tu buscador"
Soy novato en Selenium con Python y creé un script para automatizar unas consultas web. El tema es que desde hace un tiempo al abrir con el script el navegador Chrome siempre aparece el molesto mensaje de "Elige tu buscador". Es algo que antes no ocurría y si abro Chrome sin el script no aparece. Simplemente con estas 2 instrucciones ya hace que aparezca, y aunque lo marque como predeterminado, en la siguiente ejecución vuelve a mostrarlo.
Código:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

¿alguna idea de como hacer para que no vuelva a preguntar por el buscador?
Resultado:


Creo que encontré la solución, la dejo por aquí por si le sirve a alguien más:
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()


Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada.
